# VMWare Workstation - this host supports Intel VT-x

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, vt-x

i have Ubuntu 64bit Boot disk , i configured everythihng in VMWare , created virtual machine ....
and when i power on the virtual machine , there is a black screen with VMWare Logo on it and loading then a error pops on with error :

```
This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operation systems.
However, 64-bit operation in not possible

This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled

Intel VT-x might be disabled if it been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has been power-cyclen since changing this setting.

(1) Verify that BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution'.

(2)Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

(3)Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Workstation

(4)Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the lastest version.
```

My Info :

```
Sony/Vaio VGN-FW378J
Windows 10 64-bit
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU p8600 @ 2.40GHz 2.40 GHz
4.00 GB Ram
```

I only updated BIOS driver ( i downloaded update from sony site )

How I Can Fix This ?

Thanks,

Comment: have you entered the BIOS and enabled VT-x? its usually under the Security page.

Comment: where is the security tab :O ?

Comment: If you cannot find it yourself, please consult the manual for your device or ask Sony for assistance. It is entirely possible that they have disabled it in your bios (HP hides stuff in the bios configuration all the time).

Comment: umm... i found out where is BIOS , BIOS will start in sony when you press F2 on pc startup so, i checked out the security page but there is only Machine and User password set :\

Comment: ok poke around the other screens. Some vendors put it under security, others may not.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable virtualization in the BIOS.

For Sony machines specifically, here is how to enable Intel VT from their [support page](https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/31846/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDUxODQwMTc4L3NpZC9Cc0NKakNGbQ%3D%3D):

> 1. Turn off the computer.
> 2. Turn on the computer.
> 3. At the **VAIO** screen, press the **F2** key.
> 4. In the **Setup Utility** screen, press the right-arrow key until the Advanced tab is selected.
> 5. On the **Advanced** tab, press the down-arrow key until **Intel(R) Virtualization Technology** is selected and then press the **Enter**
>    key. [image]
> 6. Press the down-arrow key to select **Enabled** and then press the **Enter** key.
> 7. Press the right-arrow key until the **Exit** tab is selected.
> 8. Press the down-arrow key until **Exit Setup** is selected and then press the **Enter** key. In the **Save & Reset** screen, verify
>    **Yes** is selected and then press the **Enter** key.
>
> **NOTE**: The computer will restart automatically.